# Should the jurisdictional state be part of the title?

Tags: discussion

We already have tags, and I haven't seen any questions with "United States" or "U.S." in the title.

Yet for some state-related questions, e.g. California or Texas, it's been suggested that state should be part of the title.

Doesn't this show prejudice in what the title should be in regards to US federal vs. state laws, vs. the rest of the world?

Comment: The issue in the U.S. is that different areas are governed by federal or state laws. Sometimes the state laws are very different, but sometimes they're consistent enough for it not to matter. I don't think it's "prejudice" regarding the U.S.; similar issues arise in the U.K. (U.K. vs. Scottish law) and Europe (E.U. versus French law).

Answer (score 10):

Many sites have struggled with similar questions (tags vs titles); there have been arguments on both sides. I'm a big proponent that a question (thus, the title) should be self contained and we should ***not* rely on tags** to establish context.

The counter-argument is that is becomes somewhat tedious to have *every* question end in *"…in the United states."* It turns out that we're both right.

So generally speaking, if the jurisdiction can fit *naturally* and it makes the question more clear, I say ***use it.*** For example, saying, "Does US Copyright law allow for..." can sound just as *natural* as, "Does Copyright law..." But you don't have to force it.

We should always strive to make titles clear as possible, but they should be easy to read and understand, too. Use your judgement and edit titles to be as clear as possible. They are the main signage and billboard/welcoming mat to your site.

Relevant: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/260340) on Meta SE

Comment: I agree. It may also be appropriate to specify a jurisdictional scope at the beginning of the question: "Under California law..." or "If something happens in California..." Also, this issue is likely to come up a little ways into the editing process, because it's not necessarily obvious to a non-expert whether, in U.S. law, the state matters.